# ::befor & ::after appearance in inspector window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I noticed recently that something is related to CSS3 and some DOM elements that kind of make ::before and ::after appear in the inspector window. I wonder why they appear there?

The sample is as follows:
[image: Inspector snippet that shows befor-after appearance]

Comment: Please post a snippet from your _Layout file where you include Bootstrap via MaxCDN. It would also be helpful to see your "View part" as well, where you attempt to use some Bootstrap classes.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Get a Local Copy of Bootstrap**

If you can't access Bootstrap from the CDN, you'll need to pull it in via NuGet or your preferred package manager (npm, bower, etc.). This will download the files into your solution so that they don't require any external connections.

Additionally, you can [download Bootstrap directly](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) if you would prefer that approach.

**Reference the Local File**

Once you have it in your solution, you'll just need to reference it by location within the `<head>` section of your `_Layout.cshtml` file:

```
<!-- Point to the location within your solution that Bootstrap is stored -->
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Or you can simply drag-drop it from your Solution Explorer :

[image]

If you are still encountering issues, consider checking the Developer Tools (F12) within your browser and clearing your cache to ensure the latest files are being pulled properly.

Comment: No its not working. Give me some other way to get this done.
**Update: I Again ran NuGet manager to add bootstrap classes and i get all files in my content folder. Now how do i link those in my view?  **

Comment: What isn't working? Did the Developer Tools (F12) tell you anything? Are you receiving 404 errors when referencing the file?

Comment: @SorangwalaAbbasali that's actually rude, *Its not working* is base less you should have to tell what are the errors or maybe rethink over you statement " You are a developer" ?

Comment: @SorangwalaAbbasali Alright, now that you have the files within your Content folder, you simply need to create a `<link>` tag that points to the specific file in question within the `<head>` section of your `_Layout.cshtml` file. IIRC, you can just drag-drop it into the View and it will render the appropriate tag. I'll add an example demonstrating this.

Comment: Thanks that is error free now. It w\solved my problem.